# my web share API is supported by chrome in localhost but not supported once I host my website?

Tags: javascript, web-share

while i was working in localhost my web share code is working perfectly but when i hosted my website same code stopped working. my code is still working in localhost server but not in hosted server.

this is my code:

```
<li class="post-menu-item share_btn" id="'.$post_id.'">Share</li>
```

actually it is written under php so it has id="'.$post_id.'" in it.

this is my web share API code:

```
$(".share_btn").click(function(e) {
const post_id = $(this).attr("id");
const link = 'http://localhost/hypeup/post/' + post_id + '/';
if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
            title: 'My awesome post!',
            text: 'This post may or may not contain the answer to the universe',
            url: link,
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Thanks for sharing!');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`Couldn't share because of`, err.message);
        });
} else {
    console.log('web share not supported');
}});
```

Comment: Your link ````http://localhost/hypeup/post```` has a hard coded "localhost", did you also update that to your new domain name?

Comment: Change localhost/hypeup with your domain address

Comment: I have already done that but it's still not working.

Comment: (It would be semantically nicer to use a `<button>` instead of a `<li>` as your share button.) My hunch is that the `link` variable gets not properly set. Can you verify this (and not hard-code the origin to `"localhost"`)? Happy to investigate if you provide a live link to your app.

Comment: Actually it started working my api is not working because at that point I didn't have HTTPS I was using HTTP for my website. Share API only works in HTTPS website......... www.postvely.com this is my website you can check it out

Answer (score 3):

The Web Share API is only available in secure contexts, that is, when your page is loaded over the `https:` protocol. When you develop locally, the browser considers `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` etc. to be secure contexts, so for development purposes you don't need to set up `https:`, only for the production site. You should configure your web server so it redirects people from `http:` to `https:`, you can find many ways of doing this summarized in [this article](https://web.dev/redirects-http/#how-to-redirect-http-traffic-to-https).